# Where should I ask a question about open hardware?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I want to ask a question regarding the development of open hardware.

Stack Overflow seems to be programming focused, Programmers is also programming focused but not technical, and Super User is more casual and hobbyist related.

Which Stack Exchange site is more suitable for that kind of question?

Comment: What kind of a question?

Comment: @Pëkka I wanna ask about why the development of open hardware doesn't pick up like open software, when there are great open hardware projects already available to be forked or evolved further.

Comment: Hmmm, that sounds like a discussion question that may not be on topic anywhere on the network.... but maybe there is a hardware site with different rules

Comment: That sounds like a great conversation starter, but not really a good SE question @NlightNFotis.

Comment: @Yannis Is it offtopic even on the [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange site](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: @NlightNFotis They have a [handful of open hardware questions](http://electronics.stackexchange.com/search?q=open+hardware+closed%3A0), but I'm not a regular on the site and I'm not sure what's on or off topic there.

Comment: If you want to know about the suitability for a certain site, you can always inform on their dedicated Meta site.

Answer (score 4):

[Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/) is now up and running. We currently have 9 [hardware](/questions/tagged/hardware) questions, and the subject is explicitly on topic. I think you'll find that your question is welcome there.

In turn, I disagree with [skrrgwasme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217610/where-should-i-ask-a-question-about-open-hardware/260364#260364) because this sounds like it could be modified to ask why the development of open hardware has not picked up like the development of open software has, a question which would have some historical basis, I think - which would be on topic. It *could* lead to a discussion in its current form, but I think you could narrow it down.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the description you've provided in the comments, I don't think there is any Stack Exchange site appropriate for your question. It is very open-ended, and broad, which is off-topic just about everywhere on the Stack Exchange network. As some of the comments suggest, it's an interesting question that could start a great discussion, but SE isn't about discussion. It's a Q&A site, not a forum.

For this reason, I disagree with HDE 226868's answer. Your specific question would be off-topic on [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/).

However, if you come up with a *specific* question about a *specific* open hardware project, it would be appropriate on [Open Source](https://opensource.stackexchange.com/). Depending on the type of question, it may also be on-topic at [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Actually, my friend over on top is correct. We embrace these questions, just like we embrace their software counterparts. The site is new, so things may not be clear if you look in something such as the help center, but feel free to come and ask us first. *hint hint, it's fine to ask it*